# page not showing mobile friendly

Tags: wordpress, mobile, seo, wordpress-theming

I'm getting "Not Mobile Friendly" error in Google search console of my webmaster tools. These errors are only for all single posts/pages. The homepage is still mobile friendly.

Check it:

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftechreviewpro.com%2Ffree-online-photo-converters-9723%2F

I think this is because of some customization fault because the single pages in mobile devices don't fit to screen; instead, they float left or right.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Possible solution to the below problems

- Links too close together - Increase the hit area of the links and add padding
- Content wider than screen - use media queries, set content width to 100% and make sure content doesn't have text-overflow: wrap; applied on text.